# change the Text of Button

Tags: c#-4.0, datagridview, windows

I have a Button in `datagridview` and its text is `Start` so when I *Click* on it the text now should be `Stop` and when I click again the text should be Start.

So i have written code but its didnt work for me

```
 private void dgvCampaign_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control is Button)
        {
            Button btn = e.Control as Button;
            if(btn.Text=="Start")
                btn.Text = "Stop";
            else
                btn.Text = "Start";
        }
    }
```

Comment: *What* doesn't work? Is there an error? Does it not change the caption?

Comment: No its not Error but the it doesnt change..

Comment: Did you debug? Did you check if you ever go into the `if (e.Control is Button)` statement?

Comment: even my breakpoint hasnt reach to this event

Comment: Did you check if the event is registered on your dgvCampaign control?

Comment: I have also one more event in that and that is dgvCampaign_CellContentClick.my debug point has reach to this event but i am not sure why my debug point hasnt reach to the event dgvCampaign_EditingControlShowing

Comment: Yes i have checked and the event is registered on this control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `CellContentClick event`

```
    private void dataGridView2_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
        {
            if (dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString().Length > 0)
            {
                if (dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString() == "Start")
                {
                    dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = "Stop";
                }
                else
                {
                    dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = "Start";
                }
            }
            else
                dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value = "Start";

        }
    }
```